# figure* environment skips page while using two-column document

Tags: floats, page-breaking, two-column

I was told to use `table*` rather than the `table` environment to insert a table in a two-column document which is too small to fit in a single column. When I try to do the same thing with a figure, The figure chooses to move to a page of its own. How do I prevent this? The same thing happens in the `article` class

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt]{apa6}
\begin{document}

Why does the figure skip this page?

\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=400 pt, height=200 pt]{test.pdf}
           \caption{test.} 
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: Page 1]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: Untested, so only comment, try adding `[!htbp]` after `\begin{figure*}`, this makes LaTeX try to place it in the current place or at the top/bottom of a page before sending it to a page of its own.

Comment: Also, LaTeX allows a picture to take only a certain percentage of the pageheight if that page also includes text to prevent having only a few lines that are easily missed, see for example this answer by Frank Mittelbach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/46598

Comment: @hugovdberg I've tried `[!htbp]` before I posted here. In fact, I've also tried reducing the image size to `[width=100 pt, height=100 pt]`. I've also tried this in the `article` class. Either and all of those don't work. There must be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Does this also occur with non-pdf images (jpg, eps, whatever)? I just noticed you include a pdf, perhaps that causes a new page to occur. (Sorry I can't test easily at the moment, on my phone right now ;))

Comment: yes. in fact you can remove `\includegraphics{test.pdf}` line completely and the same issue occurs

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Double column floats always go on the *next* page at the earliest (they can't be placed on the current page as the first column may already have been set full height, so in a real document you just need to move the `figure*` environment earlier in the source, so that it is seen before the text that ends on that page. In the rare cases that you want the float at the top of the first page, you don't want a float at all and you can simply use

```
\twocolumn[{\includegraphics{...}}]
```

and put the image in the two column box at the top.

Comment: thank you, it helped

Answer (score 6):

According to the [LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) page on wikibooks `figure*` and `table*` by default "can be placed only at the top of a page or on their own page". Since LaTeX doesn't want to start the document with a float, and it can't place it at the bottom, it drifts to the next page where it is placed at the top. The `dblfloatfix` package solves this partially by allowing these floats to be placed at the bottom of a page as well (still no `h` option!). However, this does not work for the first page with the global `twocolumn` switch.

Another option is to drop this `twocolumn` option and instead use multicolumn environments, some examples how to do this can be found on [this page](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=10661) (including a way to include single column floats, as the unstarred floats don't work in `multicolumn`).

Your code adapted with `dblfloatfix` to allow a float at the bottom of a page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt]{apa6}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[6]

\begin{figure*}[b]% Force the float to the bottom of the page (but still not page 1)
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=100pt]{test.pdf}
    \caption{test.} 
\end{figure*}

\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For bottom placement of a large figure* in twocolumn I found that the `nidanfloat` package works best as it doesn't force the figure to be on the next page like `dblfloatfix` does.

Comment: This worked like charm, thank you kind sir.