# Two-column figure at beginning of appendix

Tags: floats, two-column, appendices

My two-column document has an Appendix, and I would like to put a two-column Figure at the beginning of the Appendix.

I tried to use the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[4]

\clearpage

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\begin{figure*}[t]
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this (The Figure was placed on the last page):

[image]
[image]
[image]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167186/figure-environment-skips-page-while-using-two-column-document) asks something similar, but it does not ask about the Appendix (or right after clearing the page). Also, the suggested solution with `\twocolumn[...]` does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: a full-width float can only go at the top or bottom of a two-column page (and at the bottom only on a non-first page with a special package).  the question [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430) offers a hackish workaround that involves setting a full-width block in the narrower left-hand column and forcing a compensating blank area in the right-hand column.  although the code given is for the bottom of the page, it can also work higher up.  requires iteration to get the dimensions right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the stfloats package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[4]

\clearpage

\begin{figure*}[!t]
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure*}


\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\blindtext[4] \blindtext[4] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two column figures always come at the earliest at the page after their position in the source, but here for reasons that are not totally apparent at present the `\clearpage` before the figure is affecting the placement. (Or at least it's not clear how to flush all the floats at that point without using `\clearpage` in a way that affects the position of the following floats)

However as there are no pending floats here you can remove the clearpage:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[4]

%\clearpage

\begin{figure*}[!t]
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
A very wide figure that spans across two columns.
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure*}

\newpage



\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```