# How to fix image positioning in IEEEtrans format?

Tags: graphics, floats, ieeetran

[image][image]
Can anyone help me with the positioning of the image in Project description?

Comment: it is impossible to debug an iamage, please always post small test documents as text. However `figure*` does not support `h` or `b` so your figure is set with `[!tp]`  and spanning two-column figures always come, at the earliest, on the page after their position in the source file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly it's putting the image at the top of the second page. Whereas I want it to come in the first page.

Comment: you can not use figure* in that case

Comment: unrelated but why have you got `\textnormal{`... around your text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But I want the 5 images in series, Let me update the question with the image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ```\texnormal{..``` I think that's the standard format for text in IEEE conferences. I just got this template, not sure about why it's used.

Comment: No, the `\textnormal` is  wrong But please do not post code as images, it is impossible to debug anything if you post in that form.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167203/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When to use \textnormal? should I cover the text part with \text{.. instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91527/discussion-between-raghavendra-s-s-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.9\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{T1.png}
\caption{First subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{T2.png}
\caption{Second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{T3.png}
\caption{Third subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{T4.png}
\caption{Fourth subfigure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{T5.png}
\caption{Fifth subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Input Images}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

(it is follow-up answer to your previous question. actually it cover also this question)

[image]