# Insert single column image after starting list in multicolumn

Tags: graphics, floats, multicolumn, multicol

I am writing an exam. Using a 2-column layout with `\begin{multicols}{2}`, which works fine.

The exam is a multiple-choice question set; hence I have a nested enumerate starting immediately after beginning multicolumn and ending immediately before multicolumn.

So far, so good.

The rub is that occasionally, a batch of questions refers to a diagram or table. On these occasions, I would like to insert such diagram/table in a single column (i.e. spanning the 2 columns) so that they are legible.

Of course, since I am already inside an enumerate, LaTeX throws an error if I try to end multicolumn, insert chart, and begin multicolumn again.

I saw `float` mentioned somewhere, but not sure of whether it does the trick. To be clear, if the inserted/floated object spans all columns of my multicolumn environment, that is 100% acceptable.

I have tried `figure`, but anything inside this environment completely disappears.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \exbatch{Questions 4 is based on the following table: }
    \includegraphics{test1_q4_sample}
    \end{figure}
```

PARTIALLY SOLVED: Replaced `{figure}` with `{figure*}` environment, and it sorta worked - `h` placement still doesn't work. `t` works, but pushes the image to the next page, irrespective of whether there's something before the figure or not on the page.

Turns out [there is no solution to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167203/244262), and `{figure*}` environment has no `h`, which explains the above issue.

Comment: Also, multicols doesn't support floats.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

BTW, I know `emumitem` supports a `[resume*]` option, but it seems to only work locally, not globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\savenum}{}% reserve global name

\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\xdef\savenum{\theenumi}% current counter
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{\savenum}% global resume*
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

Based on leandriis' comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[series=questions]
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[resume=questions]
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the `resume`option offered by the `enumitem` package: If you use `\begin{enumerate}[series=myseries]` for the first `enumerate` environment, you can use `\begin{enumerate}[resume=myseries]` without manually storing and alter on setting the counter.

Comment: @leandriis - Thanks!  Although isn't that precisely what enumitem is doing (with a macro name based on the series name)?

Comment: I suppose so. But since you added a remark on `resume*` not being applicable in this case, I just wanted to point out the `resume*=〈series〉` version, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're doing from your question courtesy of phrasing like:

> hence I have a nested enumerate starting immediately after beginning multicolumn and ending immediately before multicolumn.

I'm guessing from this that you're using `begin{multicols}{2}`…`\end{multicols}` for your answer choices only (or maybe it's the questions themselves).

So I'll consider two possible scenarios:

**Scenario 1: You don't actually need a `figure` environment**

Since you're talking about using the `h` placement and your example doesn't show you using a `\caption` command, why don't you just write:

```
\exbatch{Questions 4 is based on the following table: }
\includegraphics{test1_q4_sample}
```

where you want the figure to appear without wrappign it in `figure`?

I have no idea what `\exbatch` does but it appears to be putting a label of sorts on your graphics. You probably want to define a new command that would wrap both commands up in a single command and perhaps surround them with `{\centering`…`}` as well, but you can then get on with your exam writing.

**Scenario 2: You actually do need a `figure` environment**

This seems unlikely from your description, but assuming that you do indeed want to have floating figures, don't use the `multicols` environment for your two columns. Instead use LaTeX's built-in `\twocolumn` command. This is, in some ways, more capable than `multicols` and in other ways less capable. What you get:

- Single-column floats including footnotes

What you lose:

- Automatic balancing of columns at document's end
- Mid-page switches between two columns and single columns (but see below)

There is a limited ability to put single-column material at the top of the page where the two column begins. This is managed by using the optional argument on the `\twocolumn` command, e.g.,:

```
\twocolumn[\maketitle]
```

Note also, that if you're using one of the base document classes, like `article`, there is a `twocolumn` option on the document class that will automatically put the title into the full width on the first page before typesetting the rest of the document in two columns.